# Find overlapping data in a list

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to find some overlapping data in this list.

I do not have a way to group this.

How can I get the results as shown below?

Data in table:

```
PLAN_MIN    PLAN_MAX
220554          229079
220554          229079 
2210A5          2210A5 
2210A8          2210A8 
2220A5          2220A5 
2220A8          2220A8 
2230A5          2230A5 
2230A8          2230A8 
260554          267566 
2610A5          2610A5 
2610A8          2610A8 
2620A5          2620A5 
2620A8          2620A8
```

*Results:*

```
PLAN_MIN    PLAN_MAX    PLAN_MIN_1  PLAN_MAX_1
2210A5          2210A5          220554          229079
2210A8          2210A8          220554          229079
2220A5          2220A5          220554          229079
2220A8          2220A8          220554          229079
2230A5          2230A5          220554          229079
2230A8          2230A8          220554          229079      
2610A5          2610A5          260554          267566
2610A8          2610A8          260554          267566
2620A5          2620A5          260554          267566
2620A8          2620A8          260554          267566


create table plan_details
(PLAN_MIN   varchar2(20)
,PLAN_MAX   varchar2(20)
);
insert into plan_details values ('220554','229079' );
insert into plan_details values ('2210A5','2210A5' );
insert into plan_details values ('2210A8','2210A8' );
insert into plan_details values ('2220A5','2220A5' );
insert into plan_details values ('2220A8','2220A8' );
insert into plan_details values ('2230A5','2230A5' );
insert into plan_details values ('2230A8','2230A8' );
insert into plan_details values ('260554','267566' );           
insert into plan_details values ('2610A5','2610A5' );
insert into plan_details values ('2610A8','2610A8' );
insert into plan_details values ('2620A5','2620A5' );
insert into plan_details values ('2620A8','2620A8' );
commit;
```

Comment: How exactly do you know when "plan_min_1" and "plan_max_1" change in your final results?  Are all these values strictly numbers, where the others have an "A" in them?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Have you tried anything as yet? If so please mention it here and state what went wrong with it. That way you're likely to get a better response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my approach.  Each record is going to be assigned to a group, specifying the "group" it belongs to.  In your example, there are two groups.  The groups do not overlap, but the rows in them do.

How to find the groups?  Well, a group starts where the `plan_min` value does not overlap with anything else.  It then continues up to -- but not including -- the next row where the plan min does not overlap.

So the following query finds where the groups start.  It then does a cumulative sum to calculate the groups.  The final query does the `join` and book-keeping to get the data in the format you request:

```
with groups as (
      select pd.*, sum(isbegin) over (order by plan_min) as grp
      from (select pd.*,
                   (select (case when count(*) = 0 then 1 else 0 end)
                    from plan_details pd2
                    where pd2.plan_min < pd.plan_min and
                          pd2.plan_max > pd.plan_min
                   ) as IsBegin
            from plan_details pd
           ) pd
     )
select g.plan_min, g.plan_max, gg.min_plan_min, gg.max_plan_max
from groups g join
     (select grp, min(plan_min) as min_plan_min,
             max(plan_max) as max_plan_max
      from groups
      group by grp
     ) gg
     on g.grp = gg.grp;
```

This has been tested on your SQL Fiddle, so you can try it out there.

EDIT:

This is the OP's final answer:

```
SELECT a.plan_min as plan_min, a.plan_max as plan_max , b.plan_min as range_min,
       b.plan_max as range_max
FROM (SELECT p.*, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY plan_min, plan_max) rnum
      FROM plan_details p
     ) a,
     (SELECT p.*, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY plan_min, plan_max) rnum
      FROM plan_details p
     ) b
WHERE a.rnum <> b.rnum AND
      (a.plan_min between b.plan_min and b.plan_max OR
       a.plan_max between b.plan_min and b.plan_max
      )
ORDER BY 1,2,3,4;
```

Comment: Thank You for your response and letting me know about SQL Fiddle. Is this only for mySQL. Can you please let me know how to test oracle queries?

Comment: @user3225032 . . . SQL Fiddle lets you test Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, SQLite, and Postgres.  It's great, isn't it!

Comment: ya sql fiddle is great. This is the query I wrote -   SELECT a.plan_min as plan_min
      ,a.plan_max as plan_max
      ,b.plan_min as range_min
      ,b.plan_max as range_max
FROM (SELECT p.*
            ,row_number() OVER (ORDER BY plan_min, plan_max) rnum
      FROM plan_details p
     ) a,
     (SELECT p.*
            ,row_number() OVER (ORDER BY plan_min, plan_max) rnum
      FROM plan_details p
     ) b
WHERE a.rnum <> b.rnum
  AND (a.plan_min between b.plan_min and b.plan_max
       OR 
       a.plan_max between b.plan_min and b.plan_max
       )
ORDER BY 1,2,3,4;

Answer (score 1):

I take this as a riddle. You could get the results shown in the question with this query:

```
select x.PLAN_MIN, x.PLAN_MAX
, (select max(PLAN_MIN) from PLAN_DETAILS
   where PLAN_MIN <= substr(x.PLAN_MIN,1,4)
   and PLAN_MIN not like '%A%'
  ) as PLAN_MIN_1
, (select max(PLAN_MAX) from PLAN_DETAILS 
   where PLAN_MIN <= substr(x.PLAN_MIN,1,4)
   and PLAN_MIN not like '%A%'
  ) as PLAN_MAX_1
from PLAN_DETAILS x
where x.PLAN_MIN like '%A%'
order by 1, 2;
```